# Is it possible to refresh split view list using lwc or any custom code?

Tags: lightning-web-components

Let's say I'm doing some custom things on the contact record page and at the end of this custom thing, I want my lwc to refresh the list view that is shown on the split view. I have a trigger on the backend that changes the contact record so that it is no longer part of the list view.

Things I have tried that have not worked:

$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire(); (works sometimes, I believe this is not recommended)

notifyRecordUpdateAvailable (I pass the contact id into this method, doesn't seem to work)

RefreshView Api

[image]

Comment: Did you try using https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/data-refreshview-api.html.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this with "RefreshView API" and it works well.

Added a component on page, changed the name of the record from anonymous apex.
And then fired the refresh API like below.

```
import {LightningElement} from 'lwc';
import { RefreshEvent } from "lightning/refresh";

export default class FireRefreshEvent extends LightningElement {

    fireRefreshEvent(event) {
        this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent());
    }
}
```

And it refreshes the list view.

Comment: This works but try this example: You have a list view of contacts whose birthday is in this month, use anonymous apex to change one of the contact's birthday to not this month then try triggering your refresh event. Ideally it should remove that contact from the list view since we changed the contacts birthday but that contact will remain in that list view. It will only go away if I click the browser refresh button or the refresh button on the split view. You can use any custom list view, I just used birthday as an example.